# Prettier not formatting empty line properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, prettier

In my React Native code below, I'm expecting **prettier** to remove the empty line but it doesn't.

```
screenOptions={{
  headerTitleStyle: {
    color: "#a41034",

    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Prettier doesn't remove singular blank lines (in general).

From the ["empty lines" docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/rationale.html#empty-lines):

> [Prettier preserves] empty lines the way they were in the original source code. There are two additional rules:
>
> - Prettier collapses multiple blank lines into a single blank line.
> - Empty lines at the start and end of blocks (and whole files) are removed. (Files always end with a single newline, though.)

Additionally, multi-line objects are not collapsed into single-lines if there's a newline after the opening curly brace.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well. However, my doubt grew when prettier did indeed remove an empty line from the following code: https://codepen.io/alishehzad/pen/yLYNmQY?editors=0010 but failed to do so in my code in the question. Both of these are not code blocks hence the empty line should be removed in neither, right?

Comment: @AliShehzad That's JSX, not an object--I suspect it's simply Prettier treating the two syntaxes differently, but I couldn't find anything in the docs about it, and I'm not going to dig into the code for now :)

Comment: Yeah you're right. I found an issue on GitHub where this JSX syntax is discussed. Link: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6047

Comment: @AliShehzad Ah, interesting discussion there--thanks for the link, nice to understand the behavior difference :)

Comment: is there a way to configure Prettier to stop collapsing multiple blank lines into one?

Comment: @knocte :shrug: Don’t know; Prettier is pretty opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

- in the file, in vsc, press F1
- then type: Format Document With...
- when options come up, on the bottom you will see SELECT DEFAULT FORMATER
- select Prettier

also in your VSC, click on file -> preferences -> settings -> type: format default, there will be an option: Editor Default Fromatter (drop down), set this to Prettier

its just that some files like JSX/TSX need you to assign them a default formatter, otherwise they will use something like TypeScript formatter, and it will retain blank spaces.